# HTML/PHP/JavaScript tracking code always rewrites & to &amp; (or leaves &amp;); any way to keep this parameter unchanged?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, entity

I've been working, for a bit here, on installing a wicked simple (famous last words) bit of iframe tracking code to the *success.phtml* page for some conversion offers on a site that I'm contracted to do development on.  Here's what the code currently looks like:

```
<!-- Offer Conversion: Redacted -->
<iframe src="http://redacted.go2cloud.org/aff_l?offer_id=4&amp;amount=<?php echo $affiliateTotal; ?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
<!-- // End Offer Conversion -->
```

Of course, when the page renders the src URL, and either an '&' or a literal ampersand HTML entity (the one prior to the amount parameter) both result in the same things in the URL (ampersand entity, no matter what), this breaks the data that we're trying to pass on to the metrics system, due to the malformed URL.

Does anybody know of a good way to be able to include a literal URL, or piece one together in some PHP or JavaScript, that'll allow me to preserve that '&' the way I need it?  I would be grateful for anything that you might be able to point me at.

Thanks for your time & help on this issue.

-Damon

Comment: You should just be able to use a regular `&` as HTML output in a regular PHP file, there's nothing special required to render one. If you put in a regular `&` and it turns into `&amp;`, something is URL encoding it someplace else in your output flow.

Comment: I second @ahoffner's comment and ask if you have any framework or deployment system that might be escaping the `&` character? PHP and HTML alone won't escape `&`

Comment: Yeah a regular `&` is turning into `&amp;`; I figured something else is doing URL encoding and I'm trying to figure out what it might be and/or how to get around it.

This project is part of **Magento 1.9.x CE**, so there are an unbelievable number of things that could be doing the URL rewriting.